# Lightning circular rebalance never succeeds

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

I've tried using lnd, lnd-rebalance, Ride the Lightning, and Thunderhub. I've tried raising fees to a silly amount, and rebalances as low as 50k sats. I am participating in a number of triangle swaps, and have tried rebalancing between matched peers. When I first started, I was able to rebalance a few times, but I haven't gotten a single one to work in about a month now. Any ideas for how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get some rebalances of up to 100k sats working using rebalance-lnd's `--reckless` flag with a limit of 50 sats. I'm still getting a ton of "Temporary channel failure" errors, but it's progress. Here's an example rebalance:

```
pipenv run ./rebalance.py -t <node-id> --reckless --amount 100000 --fee-limit 50
```